# How to replace the HTML within a label tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select, label

I have a `label` and a `select` dropdown list:

```
<label for="serviceID[1]">Service</label>
<select name="serviceID[1]" id="serviceID[1]" class="jq__pickedNewService">
<option value="" selected="selected">No Service Selected</option>
<option value="004">Service 1</option>
<option value="001">Service 2</option>
<option value="005">Service 3</option>
<option value="002">Service 4</option>
</select>
```

I have tried all kinds of jquery code to replace the HTML inside the label tag and I am having no success:

```
$('.jq__pickedNewService').change(function(){
  var i = 1; //for the sake of this example
  $('select.jq__pickedNewService[name="serviceID\\[' + i + '\\]"]').closest('label').html('Service Replaced'); // does not work
  $('#serviceID\\[' + i + '\\]').closest('label').html('Service Replaced'); // does not work
  $('#serviceID[1]').closest('label').html('Service Replaced'); // does not work
}); // end pickedNewService
```

Comment: Why do you need the id to have brackets in it? This is probably causing you some issues.

The simplest solution would be to give the label a unique ID and use that to update the label.

Comment: I have multiple recurrences of this label/select segment -- Over a year ago I solved the bracket problem here on SO by escaping them. The brackets and .closest('label') works elsewhere in my code. Thanks @user1116933

Comment: @H.Ferrence with your id: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLhpqs6g/1/). Usage of `#serviceID[1]` causes incorrect parsing of selector.

Comment: Awesome @Regent -- `.prev()` did the trick. Thanks !!!!

Comment: There are many other answers here -- and they should work. However, the way my jQuery code has been structured and built (for over a year now) the `.prev()` solved it in my particular case. @Regent, if you move your comment to an answer I'll choose it.

Comment: @H.Ferrence you're welcome. Ok, I will post in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches through element and its parents. `<label>` is `<select>` previous sibling, so you can use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead:

[Small example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLhpqs6g/1/).

```
$('[id="serviceID[1]"]').prev('label').html('Service Replaced');
```

Also it's worth to mention that since `<select>` has brackets in ID, you can select it using `[id="serviceID[1]"]`, but not as `#serviceID[1]`.

And as [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLhpqs6g/2/) of `change` event handler:

```
$('.jq__pickedNewService').on("change", function()
{
    $(this).prev('label').html('Service Replaced');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.change()` to get the current value of a `select` then you can look for the text of the `option` that was selected (or you could find the value by using `$(this).val()`):

```
$("select").change(function(){
  var optionChosen = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  $("#label").html(optionChosen);   
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0p2qrraq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pick the label based on the ID of the select, you can do:

```
$('.jq__pickedNewService').change(function(){
     $('[for=' + $(this).attr('id').replace(']', '\\]').replace('[', '\\[') + ']').html('some value');
});
```

The following should also work:

```
$('.jq__pickedNewService').change(function(){
    $(this).siblings('label').html('some value');
});
```

Comment: is right about picking label based on ID instead of depending DOM model. here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lsdA4k8WFtPA98GtzwyV

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, to avoid relying on having to specify, or hard-code, specific `<label>`s and avoid relying on a specific HTML structure:

```js
// binding a change event-handler:
$('select').on('change', function() {
  // getting a list of the <label> elements associated with this
  // particular <select> element:
  var labels = this.labels,
    // getting the text of the selected option:
    opt = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

  // setting the text of all the associated <label> elements to the
  // text of the currently-selected <option>:
  $(labels).text(opt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="serviceID[1]">Service</label>
<select name="serviceID[1]" id="serviceID[1]" class="jq__pickedNewService">
  <option value="" selected="selected">No Service Selected</option>
  <option value="004">Service 1</option>
  <option value="001">Service 2</option>
  <option value="005">Service 3</option>
  <option value="002">Service 4</option>
</select>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).